# PHP: Call to a member function prepare() on null for long-processing scripts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, time

I'm working in a PHP application which allows to load long files and process it by a script. The scripts reads the whole file and makes operations on it, but when the file is heavyweight, the processing takes lot of time and after certain time, I got the error "Call to a member function prepare() on null". It's like because of the long processing, the PDO connection get lost. I've set the max_execution_time to 0, and the same for similar values. Can you help me please? Thank you.

The code I'm using to connect to de database is this:

```
$this->conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.BD_HOST.';dbname='.BD_NAME, BD_USER, BD_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

After several time running the script, the script brokes and I get the error "**PDO Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null**". I don't know if this is because of the machine features or something else wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail in the way of code or specific errors? This is way too thin on content to provide a conclusive answer.

Comment: I've just edited my question, thanks.